# iPad simulator showing app in bottom left?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

So I have my cocos2d app in iPhone dimensions, iPad users see it in the centre of their screen and can hit the X2 button view for a better view.

But out of nowhere the app has started being displayed at the bottom left of the screen in the simulator instead of the centre, why? The x2 button has also dissapeared.

Amazingly I can't find anyone having the same issue anywhere?

Comment: Sounds like a simulator bug, have you tried shutting down xcode and the simulator, cleaning project, rebuild and trying again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the target device family settings has been changed from iPhone to iPhone/iPad. You can find it in your target's build settings.

Comment: yes I did this! But why is this bad?? I want my app to run on both iPhone and iPad.

Comment: It will *always* run on an iPad. If you set it to iPhone only, it will run in the boxed/scaled mode on an iPad. Once you set it to iPhone/iPad, it will run as a native iPad application, and your code should be prepared for that (different screen resolutions etc.). TL;DR To get it to run in windowed mode on an iPad, set it back to just iPhone.

Comment: Great answer thanks. It's just I saw one guy made an app which didn't support iPad, I wonder where he set that?

Comment: Setting UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in Info.plist to require telephone capabilities.

Comment: Is that the official way? I mean in theory it's possible that Apple might add a phone to iPad 3 or 4 and bam, your iPhone only app suddenly starts to work on that iPad and will behave strangely. PS: don't ask me how an iPad phone would be used. :)

Comment: Can't think of another way, but I can't think of an instance where you don't want it to run on an iPad at all, and not because it does not have a phone!